# Loading nested JSON array with knockout js

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am trying to load a form where I can update the existing data from the database.
My Object has one nested array in inside each element in that array also have a nested array.
It looks like the following

```
{
    "Id": 13,
    "Name": "Category 1",
    "DeliveryOptions":
    [
        {
            "Id": 15,
            "DeliveryCategoryId": 13,
            "Name": "Option 1.-1",
            "DeliveryBreakPoints":
            [
                {
                    "Id": 19,
                    "DeliveryOptionId": 15,
                    "Start": 0,
                    "End": 10,
                    "Flat": 1,
                    "Variable": 2,
                    "Delete": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 16,
            "DeliveryCategoryId": 13,
            "Name": "Option1-2",
            "DeliveryBreakPoints":
            [
                {
                    "Id": 20,
                    "DeliveryOptionId": 16,
                    "Start": 0,
                    "End": null,
                    "Flat": 1,
                    "Variable": 3,
                    "Delete": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see inside the object there's an array called "DeliveryOptions" and each "DeliveryOptions" array has another array called "DeliveryBreakPoints"

I have configured knockout js model as the following

```
    function DeliveryCategory(id, name, options) {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.DeliveryOptions = ko.observableArray(options);
    }

    function DeliveryOption(id, name, breakpoint) {
        bpIdCounter = 0;
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.DeliveryBreakPoints = ko.observableArray(breakpoint);

        this.addDeliveryBreakPoint = function (option) {
            option.DeliveryBreakPoints.push(new DeliveryBreakPoint(bpIdCounter++));
        }
    }

    function DeliveryBreakPoint(id, start, end, flat, variable) {
        var self = this;
        self.Id = id;
        self.Start = start;
        self.End = end;
        self.Flat = flat;
        self.Variable = variable;
    }
```

I am passing parameters (such as id and name ...) as this code is also used to create new object.. However I am not sure if this is preventing it to get the existing model binded.
I also created a view model which looks like this

```
function DeliveryCategoryViewModel(model) {
    var self = this;
    if (model.Id > 0) {
        self.DeliveryCategory = ko.observable(model);
    } else {
        self.DeliveryCategory = ko.observable(new DeliveryCategory(null, "", [new DeliveryOption(null, "")]));
    }

    self.addDeliveryOption = function () {
        self.DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions.push(new DeliveryOption(null, "", [new DeliveryBreakPoint(null,"0","","","","")]));
    }

    self.removeDeliveryOption = function (option) {
        self.DeliveryCategory().DeliveryOptions.remove(option);
    }

    self.removeDeliveryBreakPoint = function (option, breakPoint) {
        option.DeliveryBreakPoints.remove(breakPoint);
    }

    self.onSubmit = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "CreateDeliveryCategory",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).success(function (data) {
            window.location = data;
        }).error(function(error){
            alert(error);
        })


    }

}
```

This code is also used when I create a new delivery category from the scratch which works fine(this is why there is a check for "model.Id > 0"). It doesn't bind the model if model.id > 0. It only displays Delivery Category name and the first Delivery Option name correctly(even there are two delivery options) and the rest is just broken.

Can anyone please pinpoint what is going on?

Comment: Can you do a fiddle of your problem? or at least show us how you are loading the data, and how you have setup your view

Comment: In your second block of JS, 6th line, you create a new instance of `DeliveryOption` with only two params, not an array. Yet in the `DeliveryOption` function you don't consider a null value for this property - while you can certainly send `null` into an `observableArray`, you then have a function which potentially `push`es values into this non-existant observable array.  You also have an extra param in the `new DeliveryBreakPoint` call on line 10, though this shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: I have two suggestions: (1) Ensure that `model.Id` is an `int`.   (2)  Modify your view-models to separate the observable declarations and the initialisation of the value from a param - what if the param hasn't been specified? My recommendation would be to have a new internal function at the end of your existing functions (an IIFE which is passed all the params from the outer function is what I do) and which checks each param prior to assigning it to an observable.   Lastly, have you tried simply stepping through your script?